# Nextjs: 405 when form submit POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shopify, shopify-app

Following this [tutorial](https://nextjs.org/blog/forms), I'm trying to submit a form in Nextjs but get a 405 error when trying to POST to my api route. I've tried using both axios and the fetch api. This seems like it should be simple to do but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Anything obvious I'm missing? Thanks!

**/survey/create**

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const testData = {
      title: surveyTitle,
    };

    const res = await fetch("/api/survey", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        dataName: testData,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  };
```

**/api/survey**

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify({ name: 'Success' }))
}
```

Comment: Check your routes definition. Probably you are defining API/survey as get or something different than post

Comment: @DanielCruz Checking route definition would be adding a conditional like: ` `` if (req.method === 'POST')```, correct?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code. Your API route `handler` should always return `200` no matter what method you use for the request. In the devtools Network tab, do you see the request being made against the expected endpoint when `handleSubmit` gets called? Also, what happens if you try to access `/api/survey` from the browser directly?

Comment: @juliomalves Going directly to the URL prints the JSON object to the screen: `{"name":"Success"}` so that tells me the route is working and it's an issue with the client talking to the api. Devtools shows that we're going to the right route: `/api/survey`, `Request Method: POST`, `Status Code: 405`, `Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. For the api call, do I need to put the entire path? From the Nextjs docs it looks like `/api/survey` is ok

Comment: The request should work with a relative path, like you're doing now. Have you tried deleting the `.next` folder in your Next.js project, then running the dev server again?

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled just now but no dice. Could the issue be that `POST` is not allowed in the response header? https://snipboard.io/u8PKS6.jpg

Comment: Ah, could very well be - but that's not configured in Next.js, that restriction is probably imposed by ngrok (or whatever the production site is hosted on). You shouldn't have that issue in local development.

Comment: So I scaffolded a new project using Shopify's CLI (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-node), created the same route setup as above and ran into the exact same issue. Not 100% sure what this tells me quite yet but it confirms that the issue is not just with my implementation. I'm going to keep experimenting but this is really strange.

Comment: Also facing same issue.

Comment: @InquisitiveTom any news or solution found?